# Merge multiple SQL files into a single SQL file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to merge multiple SQL files into a single SQL file. All I could find over the internet is to create a batch file and execute all the files. However, I want to create a single script file. Any help would be appreciated?

Also, can this be done using C#?

Comment: "SQL file"? Do you mean SQL queries, stored in files on a hard drive? Have you looked at Stored Procedures?

Comment: Read each file as text and append to your master script.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Any help with code?

Comment: I don't see any code that I can help with. Even if you are a beginner with c# you can easily find how to read and write text files online. At least try then ask for help if you get stuck. that's how SO it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 7):

assuming your files are in one place/folder

you can use like this from the command line in windows,

cd c:\folder

for %F in (*.sql) do ( type %F >> final.sql )

Note:
>> is used for appending to an existing file, wherein > will overwrite the file everytime