# powershell - read all .sql files in a folder and save them all into a single .sql file without changing line ends or line feeds

Tags: powershell, file, automation

I manage database servers and often I have to apply scripts into different servers or databases.

Sometimes these scripts  are all saved in a directory and need to be open and run in the target server\database.

As I have been looking at automating this task I came across [how Run All PowerShell Scripts In A Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27851443/1501497) and also [How can I execute a set of .SQL files from within SSMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840847/1501497) and that is exactly what I needed, however I stumbled over a few issues:

1. I don't know the file names

   `:setvar path "c:\Path_to_scripts\"`

   `:r $(path)\file1.sql`

   `:r $(path)\file2.sql`
2. I tried to add all .sql files into one big thing, but when I copied from powershell into sql, in many of the procedures that had long lines, the lines got messed up

   `cls`

   `$Radhe = Get-Content 'D:\apply all scripts to SQLPRODUCTION\*.sql' -Raw`

   `$Radhe.Count`

   `$Radhe.LongLength`

   `$Radhe`
3. If I could read all the files in that specific folder and save them all into a single `the_scripts_to_run.sql` file, without changing the line endings, that would be perfect.

I don't need to use `get-content` or any command in particular, I just would like to get all my scripts into a big single script with everything in it, without changes.

How can I achieve that?

I even found [Merge multiple SQL files into a single SQL file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52702203/1501497) but I want to get it done via powershell.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine, I'm not sure what you mean by not needing to use `Get-Content` you could use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( )` or `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( )` but this should work fine too. Try it and let me know if it works.

```
$path = "c:\Path_to_scripts"
$scripts = (Get-ChildItem "$path\*.sql" -Recurse -File).FullName
$merged = [system.collections.generic.list[string[]]]::new()

foreach($script in $scripts)
{
    $merged.Add((Get-Content $script))
}

$merged | Out-File "$path\mergedscripts.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like me and [@Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081892/1501497) had the same idea:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Filter "*.sql" | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File $Path\stuff.txt -Append utf8
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually much simpler than the proposed solutions. `Get-Content` takes a list of paths and supports wildcards, so no loop is required.

```
$path = 'c:\temp\sql'

Set-Content -Path "$path\the_scripts_to_run.sql" -Value (Get-Content -Path "$path\*.sql" -Raw)
```